# Нужен дискорд бот

Tags: python, discord, бот

Мне нужно чтобы бот "видел" реакцию :white_check_mark: в определённом канале. И если он "увидит" реакцию, то должен выдать роль. пишу на discord.py. Т.к новичок в работе с дискорд ботами не сильно знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  channel_id = '<id>' # замени на реальное айди 
  if reaction.message.channel.id != channel_id:
      return
  if reaction.emoji == "✓":
      role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="<rolename>") # замени на настоящие имя роли 
      await client.add_roles(user, role)
...
```

Comment: а где взять id канала?

Comment: @Danya Надо щелкнуть контекстно на канал и нажать `Copy ID`. Должен быть включен девелопер мод в настройках

Comment: Это нужно ID роли или название роли?

Comment: @Danya Айди канала. Роль просто по названию